# Open file in linux. I don't want to create a write-protected file

Tags: c++, linux, unistd.h

I have a problem when I create a file in Linux it makes my file write-protected and I don't know why it does that.

```
void fileOperation::openFileWrite(char x, off_t s)
{
  int fd;
  char c[2] = {x};

  fd = open("/home/stud/txtFile", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);  //open file
  if(fd == -1)
      cout << "can't open file" << endl;
  else
  {
      lseek(fd, s, SEEK_SET);//seek at first byte
      write(fd, (void*)&c, 2);//write to file
  }
  syncfs(fd);
  ::close(fd);
}
```

Comment: You should use `perror` on failure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use additional argument with write permission set (default permission for you may be taking write permission off)

```
 fd = open("/home/stud/txtFile", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);//open file
```

0666 is an octal number, i.e. every one of the 6's corresponds to three permission bits

```
6 = rw
7 = rwx
```

Comment: Thank you very much it sovled the problem.

Comment: You have to tag their name with the `@` symbol to get their attention like: @LocDaiLe

Comment: @LocDaiLe if the answer fixed your problem, be sure to mark it as correct (click the green checknext to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a restrictive `umask`.  The `open` call will simply attempt to create a file with mode 0666 but the user's umask typically removes many of those permission bits.